# Print decimal fixed-point/float formats as hexadecimal

Tags: c, math, floating-point, ieee-754, fixed-point

Adding the ability to print a decimal fixed-point number as hexadecimal in my general purpose library and realized i wasn't %100 sure how i should represent the fraction part of the number. A quick google search suggests i should:

1. Multiply by 16
2. Convert the integer part to hex and add it to the buffer
3. Get rid of the integer part
4. Repeat

As suggested here https://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/219928-how-convert-float-hex

This method is for floating-point (ieee 754 binary formats) and it works for that just fine. However, i tried to adopt this to my decimal fixed-point (scaled by 8) format, and after testing this approach on paper i noticed for some fractions (i.e. **.7**), this causes a repeating pattern of **.B3333**... and so on.
To me this looks very undesirable. I also wonder if this would case a loss in precision if i was to try to read this from a string into my fixed-point format.

Is there any reason why someone wouldn't print the fraction part like any other 2s complement hexadecimal number? i.e where **17535.564453** is printed as **447F.89CE5**

While this is targeted at decimal fixed-point, I'm looking for a solution that can also be used by other real number formats such as ieee 754 binary.

Perhaps theres another alternative to these 2 methods. Any ideas?

Comment: Why not just use the `%a` format? See here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/ It's designed precisely for the purpose of being an exact representation of the floating-point number, with no loss of precision.

Comment: @alias 2 reasons. #1 as mentioned in the question this is for my fixed-point format which wouldn't be supported. Though i would probably apply any solution found here to the IEEE 754 formats also. #2 Can't use any standard library. This really is not a question of how, but why and is there a better approach.

Comment: "where 17535.564453 is printed as 447F.89CE5" is confusing.  17535.53830432891845703125‬ (base 10)  is 447F.89CE5 (base 16) and  17535.564453 (base 10) is 447F.907FFDE... (base 16).  Explain how 17535.564453 is converted to 447F.89CE5.  That does not follow steps 1-4 above.

Comment: "I also wonder if this would case a loss in precision if i was to try to read this from a string into my fixed-point format." -->  If code reads in `.B3333...` it will never finish as that is an infinitely long input.   If code reads in _enough of _ `.B3333...`, then the precision loss can be minimal.  To now how much to read in the encoding details of "a decimal fixed-point number" needs to be posted.

Comment: Why is this tagged with IEEE-754, which is a floating-point standard, when it is about a fixed-point format? Why is it tagged with floating-point?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica The 17535.564453 to 447F.89CE5 is not about following steps 1-4 above. Read it again. I take the fraction part and treat it like any other normal 2s complement format.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I tagged floating-point and ieee-754 because i wanted to find a solution that works for both decimal fixed-point and ieee 754 binary formats.

Comment: @AlwaysNub There is no mention of 2's complement in the post.

Comment: Are you looking for the base-16 approximation to the number?  Or do you want to take the bits in the 8 bytes of DOUBLE and show exactly 16 hex digits?

Comment: @RickJames The base-16 approximation to the number

Answer (score 2):

Although the question asks about fixed-point, the C standard has some useful information in its information for the `%a` format for floating-point. C 2018 7.21.6.1 8 says:

> … if the [user-requested] precision is missing and `FLT_RADIX` is not a power of 2, then the precision is sufficient to distinguish<sup>285)</sup> values of type `double`, except that trailing zeros may be omitted;…

Footnote 285 says:

> The precision *p* is sufficient to distinguish values of the source type if 16<sup>*p*−1</sup> > *b*<sup>*n*</sup> where *b* is `FLT_RADIX` and *n* is the number of base-*b* digits in the significand of the source type…

To see this intuitively, visualize the decimal fixed-point numbers on the real number line from 0 to 1. For each such number *x*, visualize a segment starting halfway toward the previous fixed-point number and ending halfway toward the next fixed-point number. All the points in that segment are closer to *x* than they are to the previous or next numbers, except for the endpoints. Now, consider where all the single-hexadecimal-digit numbers *j*/16 are. They lie in some of those segments. But, if there are 100 segments (from two-digit decimal numbers), most of the segments do not contain one of those single-hexadecimal-digit numbers. If you increase the number of hexadecimal digits, *p*, until 16<sup>*p*−1</sup> > *b*<sup>*n*</sup>, then the spacing between the hexadecimal numbers is less than the width of the segments, and every segment contains a hexadecimal number.

This shows that using *p* hexadecimal digits is sufficient to distinguish numbers made with *b*<sup>*n*</sup> decimal digits. (This is sufficient, but it may be one more than necessary.) This means all the information needed to recover the original decimal number is present, and avoiding any loss of accuracy in recovering the original decimal number is a matter of programming the conversion from hexadecimal to decimal correctly.

Printing the fraction “like any other hexadecimal number” is inadequate if leading zeroes are not accounted for. The decimal numbers “3.7” and “3.007” are different, so the fraction part cannot be formatted merely as “7”. If a convention is adopted to convert the decimal part **including trailing zeros* to hexadecimal, then this could work. For example, if the decimal fixed-point number has four decimal digits after the decimal point, then treating the fraction parts of 3.7 and 3.007 as 7000 and 0070 and converting those to hexadecimal will preserve the required information. When converting back, one would convert the hexadecimal to decimal, format it in four digits, and insert it into the decimal fixed-point number. This could be a suitable solution where speed is desired, but it will not be a good representation for human use.

Of course, if one merely wishes to preserve the information in the number so that it can be transmitted or stored and later recovered, one might as well simply transmit the bits representing the number with whatever conversion is easiest to compute, such as formatting all the raw bits as hexadecimal.

Comment: I'm having a hard time visualizing your description of using p hexadecimal digits. I will work on this to figure it out and report back with the results. Until then you have my up-vote. Thanks

Comment: @AlwaysNub: Imagine the 100 decimal values .00, .01, .02,… .98, .99 spread out between 0 and 1. Where do the 16 hexadecimal values .0, .1, … .A, .B, .C, .D, .E, .F lie? Obviously there is not a hexadecimal value between every pair of decimal values. You need 256 decimal values to ensure there is one in between every pair of decimal values. Thus, the precision used for the hexadecimal display must be **at least as fine** as the decimal precision (“fine” in the fine versus coarse sense).

Comment: Ok. I'm following you. I haven't had time to dive into this because I've been really busy all week. I will do some calculations this weekend to see how many hexadecimal digits I need.